# Oracle VirtualBox Problems in update

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I've been using *Oracle VirtualBox* for a while but now I've downloaded Genymotion Emulator and it asked me to update the vitrualbox but whenever I click on the update or to check Network Operation Manager I got this error **Oracle virtualbox the network operation failed with the following error unknown reason**
I've checked the the virtualbox forums through https://forums.virtualbox.org/ but didn't find the solution I found many people asking this question but there are no convincing solutions.

If you have any suggestions about good **virtual machines** which I can use it for Genymotion to test my android apps which are done by eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load virual box, select the Android VM and go to Settings > Network Adapter and then change the network adapter to be your PC's proper adapter, not the host only I've found this usually fixes any network related errors.

Comment: Well thanks
But I can't tick the choice _Enable Network Adapter_ and whenever I choose so other adapter and close the settings page to try to update it is not working so when I return bk to the settings page I found that it is bk to the Host.

Comment: That's very odd, never seen that before. Have you tried contacting Genymotion support, their support is pretty good when I emailed them about something

Comment: The only thing I can think of trying would be to completely uninstall Virtual Box and re-install with the latest release from the Virtualbox website

Comment: Thanks Boardy, well I didn't emailed them yet I thought I will be able to find a solution but couldn't tell now but I was planning to do as u said to uninstall it and download it again and I hope it will work if not I will e-mail them..

By the way _do we have to use_ Oracle VM VirtualBox for Genymotion or can I use the Windows Virtual PC which which is by Microsoft I guess

Comment: No, for Genymotion you have to use Oracle VirtualBox

Comment: I uninstall it and downloaded it again I mean the Oracle VirtualBox but still the same problem so I've sent an e-mail to the Genymotion support team and the replied and asked me to sent the Genymotion Log which is in Settings menu > Misc tab so I did and now I am waiting for their replay. Hope it will be solved quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade VirtualBox to version 4.13.14 manually (download it from VirtualBox site).
Details are here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13096